# Bootstrap modal opens upon successful form submit, but will not stay closed when "Close" button clicked

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a contact form that when submitted successfully, opens a Bootstrap modal letting the user know sending is successful.  It opens just fine upon success, but when I click close, it doesn't stay closed.  After a second or two it opens again and submits another form/message.  Please see code below.  I'm looping somewhere and thinking I am missing a "return" or "preventDefault()" somewhere.  Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
//var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$('#successModal').modal({
    show: false
});

$('#errorModal').modal({
    show: false
});

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$("button").click(function(e) {

    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault(e);

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function(result){
            $('#contact-name').val('');
            $('#contact-email').val('');
            $('#contact-website').val('');
            $('#contact-message').val('');

            $('#successModal').modal({
                show: true
            });

        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            //$('#errorModal').modal('show')
        }


    });



});



});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You success function calls this to show the modal, not close it. :

```
    $('#successModal').modal({
            show: true
        });
```

If you want it to close it on success,  you can use this instead

```
   $('#successModal').modal('hide');
```

or you could also add this to you submit button.

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

I don't know why you are calling this:

```
 $('#successModal').modal({
show: false
});
```

Comment: I was reading that the modal first needs to be initialized, so that's where the last part came in.  But I see what you mean, that's not necessary.  The 'hide' is a good idea, but if I 'show' and then immediately 'hide' after it just flashes the modal.  Not sure if adding data-dismiss would work, since showing the modal isn't dependent on clicking submit, but rather on success of the post, unless I'm not understanding something.  The modal is to remain open after success until the user closes, the problem is that when I close it automatically reopens and submits another ajax request.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, had to give my "Submit" button a separate id.  Posting what I think was happening in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I figured this out.  My click event starting the ajax POST process is grabbing "button", well "Close" in the modal is also a "button", so when I click that it's running through the Javascript again.  I gave my "Submit" button on my form a separate id, changed it in my Javascript file and it works just fine now.  Can't believe it was that simple.